# What are some online practice exams to assess one’s level?

Tags: reference-request, proficiency-test

I’d like to do a full practice exam in preparation for a TELC exam, B2 level.

I’d prefer an online format I could do on my phone.

Is there any website with a decent digital format German exam? (I.e., as opposed to merely a PDF, which I find more difficult to go through on a phone.)

I found this (https://www.goethe.de/en/m/spr/kup/tsd.html) and it’s really what I had in mind, except I think it’s just a short assessment and I’d prefer a complete one plus the ability to do multiple if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an entire B2 mock exam: https://www.goethe.de/de/spr/kup/prf/prf/gb2/ue9.html